# How to scrape the javascript portion of a webpage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some site in Node.js. I've followed a [great tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-scraping-with-node-js-daa2027dcd3) however realize that it might not be what I am looking for, ie. might be looking at **scraping the javascript portion of the page** instead of the html one.

**Is that possible ?**

Reason for that is that I am looking for loading the content of the below portion of the code I could find by inspecting in Safari (not showing in Chrome) a kayak.com page (see url below) and seems to be in a scripting section.

```
reducer: {"reducerPath":"flights\/results\/react\/reducers\/
```

https://www.kayak.com/flights/TYO-PAR/2019-07-05-flexible/2019-07-14-flexible/1adults/children-11?fs=cfc=1;legdur=-960;stops=~0;bfc=1&sort=bestflight_a&attempt=2&lastms=1550392662619

Comment: By "scrape the JavaScript" do you mean *execute* the JavaScript so that it will modify the HTML as it would in a browser?  Or are you just literally trying to *get* the JavaScript code?

Comment: You can inspect `window.R9` in the console to check if they store this object in another variable, but it seems that it is used only in their React code `window.R9.init.push({ reducer: {"reducerPath":" })`. You can also query all script elements and run a regex to find this line.

Comment: I don't think it's stored anywhere else. How would you query all script elements? So far using puppeteer but my understanding is that is scraps only the html portion (so my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Unfortunately, this site uses bot/scrape protection: tools like `curl` get a page with bot warning, headless browser tools like `puppeteer` get a page with captcha.

===============

As this line is present in the HTML source code and is not added dynamically by JavaScript execution, you can use something like this with the appropriate library API:

```js
const extractedString = [...document.querySelectorAll('script')]
  .map(({ textContent }) => textContent)
  .find(txt => txt.includes('string'))
  .match(/regexp/);
```

Comment: Thanks but are you sure it's in the html source code? It's in the R9.react.boot() that is not loaded in the source I get when doing the below:
const rp = require('request-promise'); rp(url).then(function(html) {

Comment: Well, I've just used the Chrome dev tools network tab and search in the main response body, and the string is there.

Comment: Hm, curl returns the source without this part. It seem like a browser and not-browser clients may get different sources. I will update my answer soon.

Comment: UPDATE: Unfortunately, this site uses bot/scrape protection: tools like `curl` get a page with bot warning, headless browser tools like `puppeteer` get a page with captcha.

Comment: Thanks a lot for having checked further. What I don't get though is that inspecting the code in Safari shows me that tag as part of R9.react.boot({. So what does Safari to get this that other tools can't? Apologies for the genuine question..

Comment: Sorry, I do not know. Human client detection may be complicated technology with many features.